# Datatables column filter not working

Tags: jquery, html, datatables, server-side

Im trying to add multiple column filters to my table based on https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html
I'm using server-side option.
General search, pagination and ordering works fine.
But if I search the string "teststring" in the first column, ajax request looks like the following:

```
 ["sSearch_0"]=>
  string(10) "teststring"
 ["sSearch_1"]=>
  string(10) "teststring"
 ["sSearch_2"]=>
  string(10) "teststring"
```

If I insert another string in column 2, that string is send to sSearch_0, sSearch_1 and sSearch_2.
This behavior makes impossible to me to identify which column to filter.
My goal is to search different values on different columns and get an ajax request like:

```
["sSearch_0"]=>
      string(10) "value1"
     ["sSearch_1"]=>
      string(10) "value2"
     ["sSearch_2"]=>
      string(10) "value3"
```

This is my table:

```
<table id="tabla" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Expediente</th>
                <th>Alcance</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Expediente</th>
                <th>Alcance</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

These are my scripts

```
 <!--Datatables load-->
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#tabla').dataTable( {
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "bProcessing": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "server_side3.php?action=table_data",
            "bDeferRender": true,
            language: {
            url: '//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/380cb78f450/i18n/Spanish.json'
        }

        } );
    } );
    </script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
    $('#tabla tfoot th').each( function () {
        var title = $('#tabla thead th').eq( $(this).index() ).text();
        $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Buscar '+title+'" />' );
    } );

    // DataTable
    var table = $('#tabla').DataTable();

    // Apply the search
    table.columns().eq( 0 ).each( function ( colIdx ) {
        $( 'input', table.column( colIdx ).footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
            table
                .column( colIdx )
                .search( this.value )
                .draw();
        } );
    } );
} );
</script>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Sebastián